# 2 different answers from google

Tags: get

why I get two different answers?

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Paris%20Hilton&cr=countryUS&lr=lang_en&hl=en :

```
1- http://www.parishilton.com/
2- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Hilton
3- https://twitter.com/ParisHiltonhttps://twitter.com/ParisHilton
4- http://www.tmz.com/person/paris-hilton/
5- http://perezhilton.com/category/paris-hilton
```

https://www.google.com/search?q=Paris+Hilton&cr=countryUS&lr=lang_en&hl=en :

```
1- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Hilton
2- https://twitter.com/ParisHilton
3- http://www.parishilton.com/
4- http://www.tmz.com/person/paris-hilton/
5- http://perezhilton.com/category/paris-hilton
```

how can I get 2 the same answer?